# Mono SecureChannelFailure on HTTPS request

Tags: c#, mono

Running the following line:

```
new HttpClient().GetAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // url being an https endpoint with a valid certificate when I browse to the image from a browser
```

I get the following exception:

```
Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)
```

I tried adding the `ServicePointManager` workarounds:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (a, b, c, d) => true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Separately and together and also with this implementation of the callback:

```
public static bool ValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
        return true;

    var isOk = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < chain.ChainStatus.Length; i++)
        if (chain.ChainStatus[i].Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown)
        {
            chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;
            chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
            chain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
            chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllFlags;

            var chainIsValid = chain.Build((X509Certificate2)certificate);

            if (!chainIsValid)
                isOk = false;
        }

    return isOk;
}
```

I also tried chaging the `MONO_TLS_PROVIDER` environment variable to `btls`,`oldtls`,`legacy` but I just received a different exception:

```
Error: ConnectFailure (TLS Support not available.)
```

I am using **Mono 4.4.1** on **Linux** and I also tried to import certificates running:

```
mozroots --import --sync --url "http://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/raw-file/default/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt"
```

Comment: mono 4.4.1 doesn't include BTLS, use Mono 5.x